# Python : How to use an error out of a try/except block?

Tags: python

I have this try block in my code :

```py
try:
    installation('isc-dhcp-server')
except:
    print('Oops an error...')
    sys.exit(8)
```

Here in a try/except block the sys.exit(8) will just exit this block and keep an error with code "8". This is just what I want. Now I want to use this except somehere else in a code to avoid somes parts link to this setup. How can I do that ?

I try to put the error in a variable with :

```
except Exception as NameofError:
```

And use NameofError with a if statement but this var is not defined in the local space (I think) so I can't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initiate a variable before the try-catch block and assign the exception to it

```
caught_error = None
try:
    # some error throwing func
except Exception as e:
    caught_error = e
    # your error handling code
print(caught_error)
```

Edit: However, if you still have `sys.exit()` in your catch block you probably won't have the chance to do anything to the exception given that your program will be terminated already.

Comment: Thanks just perfect